# Parameter passed to JSP via struts to JSP variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

Im a Java newbie, I have this code working which obtains the brandCode parameter and places in a hidden input named "brandCode"

```
<html:form method="get" action="/catalogindexsearch.do" styleId="sortAndNavigationForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="formAction" value="searchDisplay" />
    <html:hidden property="brandCode" />
</html:form>
```

But I wish to use the parameter elsewhere in my JSP i.e.

```
<h1>Brand Code: ${brandCode}</h1>
```

So my question is how can I create a Java variable from the html:form URL parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was after in the end was this `${param.brandCode}` or this $`{param["brandCode"]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Give it an ID like this:

```
<html:hidden property="brandCode" id="brandcode" />
```

then access the value by:

```
var brandCode = $("#brandcode").val();
```

or if you're not using jQuery:

```
var brandCode = document.getElementById("brandcode").value;
```

If you're trying to use the value of a property from your action class, you had it right - It's

```
${brandcode}
```

where brandcode is a property in your action class with getters and setters:

```
private String brandcode;

public String getBrandCode() {

}
```

you get the point.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, you want to access the hidden value on the server?

Comment: From my limited understanding that html:form JSP code above, grabs the brandCode parameter and adds it to a brandCode hidden input, but I want to use the brandCode parameter elsewhere in the JSP?

Comment: @user1881263 What do you mean "elsewhere"? You can only use it if it's set. Before the form is submitted it's not set, and you'd have to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

In JSTL you can access a form property by form name

```
<h1>Brand Code: ${formName.brandCode}</h1>
```